# converting if statement to lambda

Tags: python, if-statement, lambda

I have such if statement:

```
if brand_text == 'eth1' and group_name == 'size':
    group_name = 'feature'
```

I need to convert it to lambda, so I tried:

```
xx = lambda one, two: 'feature' if one == 'eth1' and two == 'size' else pass
xx(brand_text, group_name)
```

But it says on place with `pass`:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Why do you even want to do this?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: It can't be unassigned, otherwise he wouldn't be able to call `xx(brand_text, group_name)`.

Comment: @TimPietzcker ah, thanks; hadn't spotted `group_name` was in the evaluation *and* the assignment

Comment: Why you need to convert to lambda?  Code obfuscation contest?

Answer (score 3):

You can't assign to `group_name` in the `lambda`, so you have to *use* the returned value:

```
group_name = xx(brand_text, group_name)
```

In the negative case you presumably want to keep the original `group_name`, so the appropriate expression would be:

```
xx = lambda bt, gn: 'feature' if bt == 'eth1' and gn == 'size' else gn
```

Answer (score 0):

`lambda` creates an anonymous function that returns a value in all cases, while the `if` statement assigns a value to `group_name` only under certain conditions. If you really want to use lambda, you will have to return `None`. Moreover, `pass` is a statement and cannot be used in-line, i.e. in-statement. This should work:

`xx = lambda one, two: 'feature' if one == 'eth1' and two == 'size' else None
xx(brand_text, group_name)`

Answer (score 0):

The only (or at least the most significant) difference between a `lambda` statement and a `def` statement is that the body of the `lambda` must be a single *expression*, whose value is implicitly returned. `pass` is a statement, and cannot be embedded in the `else` portion of the conditional expression.